# UICollectionview cells change when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

My UICollectionview looks like this:

[image]

My UICollectionviewCell contains an Image, and by setting the corner radius property I am trying to make it round, but this is the result. The same goes for my Image in my HeaderView.

Moreover do my UICollectionviewCells change when I scroll and randomly change appearance, by some finally being round, some even diamond shaped and some icons being black.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using for the CollectionviewCell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //1
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell",
                                                  for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.imageView.tintColor = UIColor.white
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.width/2


    let icon = categories[indexPath.item]?.image
    cell.nameLabel.text = categories[indexPath.item]?.name
    cell.nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.imageView.image = icon
    let selected = categories[indexPath.item]?.selected
    if selected! {
        cell.isSelected = true
        collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
        cell.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.imageView.tintColor = colors.colorBottom
    }


    return cell
}
```

Here is the code of my HeaderView:

```
//make the profileImageView round
    imageview.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageview.layer.cornerRadius = imageview.frame.height/2
    imageview.layer.borderWidth = 4
    imageview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

Comment: What is the height of your imageView

Comment: I'm using IB. The height and width are the same using Aspect Ratio 1:1

Comment: ok..what is constant height means height constraint value

Comment: imageview.layer.cornerRadius = constantHeight(like 80,100)/2, imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: @Mike have you used  `clipsToBounds  = true` for rounding the image ?If not please try this.

Comment: Create the custom collection view class and set the corner radius there.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava I did, but still the same error is happening

Comment: @Mike and you have used `masksToBounds` also? If you have used both then try only `clipToBounds` and remove `masksToBounds`

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava I removed masksToBounds and then tried clipToBounds

Comment: Where is the nameLabel in your cell. I cannot see it in the screenshot you added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** To make your `imageView` in `UICollectionViewCell` `round`, in `Storyboard`:

1. Set `UICollectionViewCell's` `clipToBounds` to `true`
2. Set `UIImageView's` `clipToBounds` to `true`
3. Set the `aspectRatio` of `imageView` = `1:1`

Remove these 2 line from `cellForItemAt`

```
cell.imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

**2.** Below line must be responsible for the `icons becoming black`

```
    cell.imageView.tintColor = colors.colorBottom
```

Check if you are changing the `selected` status in `categories` array whenever a cell is selected?

**3.** In `headerView`:

1. Set the `aspectRatio` of `imageView` = `1:1` in `storyboard`
2. From your code, remove:

`imageview.layer.masksToBounds = true`

3. In `storyboard`:  Set `UIImageView's` `clipToBounds` to `true`

**4.** **Screenshot:**

[image]

Let me know if you need any other kind of help regarding the code.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot assume that your cell's frame is recalculated after dequeue, use constant value instead:

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
```

Comment: How would I make it round then using a constant value?

Comment: I see that every cell has the same size, how do you set this size?

Comment: Using the Interface Builder with Auto-Layout